# iReport execute stored procedure not working correctly with Informix

Tags: stored-procedures, jasper-reports, informix, ireport

I'm trying to know how to call stored procedures from iReport with an Informix DB Connection. If I do a simple `select` retrieves all the columns with no problem.

Now that I must work with some data which I retrieve from a Stored Procedure. To test how to do this I made a sample SP as this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_example() RETURNING VARCHAR(100), INTEGER;
    RETURN 'some varchar', 100;
END PROCEDURE;
```

This compiles and I can execute it from my `SQL` editor. The problem comes when I want to retrieve the data from iReport, I'm just getting the first returning value (`'some varchar'`) but not the second, as shown in the screenshot:

[image: Error with SP in iReport]

What am I missing here?

My Informix version is Informix Dynamic Server 2000 Version 9.21.TC4.

Comment: There's a possibility that you're not missing anything but the software calling the stored procedure is.  One thing you could try is changing the `RETURNING` clause to `RETURNING VARCHAR(100) AS name, INTEGER AS number;`, thereby giving explicit names to the 'columns'.  There's an outside chance this might alter things — hopefully for the better — by showing the string as `name` instead of `(expression)`, and the number as `number` instead of another `(expression)`.  Or it may make no difference whatsoever.

Comment: I've tried but seems that Informix doesn't allow aliases in returning variables, it gives me a syntax error in the `AS` word when checking `RETURNING VARCHAR(100) AS name` (also `name` is a reserved word in Informix, should be `my_varchar` or something like that)

Comment: Re: 'reserved word' — yes, no, maybe, but mostly no.  That is, you can do eccentric things like `CREATE TABLE TABLE(INTEGER DECIMAL NOT NULL, NOT INTEGER NOT NULL);` in Informix because it tries to treat keywords as identifiers when the keyword makes no sense in the context.

Comment: good tip, but still not working :P

Comment: Which version of Informix are you connecting to?  I can create `CREATE PROCEDURE sp_example() RETURNING VARCHAR(100) AS name, INTEGER AS number;
    RETURN 'some varchar', 100;
END PROCEDURE;` successfully with 12.10.FC4 on a Mac, and it would have worked in 11.70.  The `AS name` notation was a more recent addition, so it might not have been in 11.50 or 11.10 or 10.00 or 9.40...but I think it was added in the 10.00 era, so anything that you're still running should support it.

Comment: My Informix version is `Informix Dynamic Server 2000 Version 9.21.TC4`

Comment: I am not sure — I'm guessing it's about a 10% chance — that the `AS name` notation will help.  I'm 99% sure that the notation should be OK as far as Informix is concerned.  Some piece of software trying to talk to Informix may be pre-parsing the SQL (SPL) and making a mess of it.

Comment: Ugh!  The notation is (was) not available in 9.21.  It was definitely added this millennium, later than 2000.  At some point, you need to upgrade.  That software is well beyond the end of its shelf life.  OK, scratch that for an idea.  I'm not sure what to suggest.  How much flexibility do you have about rewriting the stored procedure?  Do you need this to work with what you've got already, or can you write the procedures to order?  I'm guessing the former — you need this to work with procedures that already exist.  I'm not sure what to suggest, in that case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144103/discussion-between-alvaro-pedraza-and-jonathan-leffler).